# Foreach output dynamic variable outside of loop - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, foreach

I use Laravel version 5.1 and I need ideas how to output a specific dynamic variable(data-target) outside of foreach.

The modal div(bootstrap modal) it must be outside of foreach!

What is the best to use php or jquery and how to solve this problem?

Html and Laravel(php):

```
@foreach ($category as $name => $value)
<li>
<a href="">{{$value->category_name}}</a>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning fa fa-pencil-square-o pull-right easy" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$value->id}}"></button>
...
</li>
@endforeach

<div class="modal fade" id="{{$value->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Why it should be outside of `foreach`?

Comment: You can use another `foreach` for that specific element.

Comment: Because I need the specific and same id getting when I click the button. My button and the modal div must have the same id somehow.

Comment: @VasilisGreece, so you can create modals with the same or additional `foreach`. If there are just few modals and no heavy data loaded (like graphics or big texts), it's easier to do this with `foreach` rather than with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. No AJAX required or additional foreach(to prevent heavy loaded html data). It works perfectly!

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#categoryview .fa-pencil-square-o").click(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("data-target").attr("data-target", "#edit");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and simpliest way to achieve this is to create a new Route, depending on the ID of the category.

Then, create a view containing the modal content called from the controller of this Route.

After this, call a jQuery script when clicking on this edit button, which loads the modal view via an AJAX request (depending on the ID). When this request is done, insert the content into the modal and open the modal.

Comment: Yes you are right I think that is the only solution. Now I need to learn how to use AJAX requests.